# Spring MVC GET @ModelAttribute java.util.Date type with timestamp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `@RestController` that looks something like this:

```
@RestController
public class EventSearchController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/eventSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<EventDTO> eventSearch(@Valid
                                    @ModelAttribute
                                    EventSearchCommand eventSearchCommand) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

And my `EventSearchCommand` looks like this:

```
@Data
public class EventSearchCommand {

  // other fields that are not a problem here...

  private Date startDate;

  private Date endDate;
}
```

The `@Data` here comes from [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). The issue I'm having is that the startDate and endDate parameters are coming in on the GET string as

```
?endDate=1453784399000&startDate=1453698000000
```

Are not being bound properly, and I am getting this error:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type java.util.Date for property endDate; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type java.lang.String to type
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date
>   for value 1453784399000; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse 1453784399000

What kind of converter (or more ideally, `@DateTimeFormat` on the problem fields) do I need to write to get this to bind properly?

I should note that I have another controller set up exactly the same, except the object is annotated `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute` and the request body is a JSON object where the dates are passed in as integers rather than strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I work on a software project where I receive some parameters (from a GET request) and two of them are timestamp. I just use something like:

```
public ModelAndView method(@ModelAttribute("it") Long it, @ModelAttribute("ft") Long ft /* some parameters that it doesn't matter here */) {
    java.util.Date initialDate = new java.util.Date(it); //create a java.util.Date from a long representing timestamp.
    // ...
}
```

I don't know if I get you right, but it so, this piece of code can fit into yours.

Comment: I thought of doing it this way earlier, but wasn't sure if it was the most "Springy" way to do things. Thanks for the answer.